# How to use Alexa.Discovery interface with Custom Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Currently, I am using my custom skill to set the temperature of my thermostat..
First I speak the Invocation command: "Alexa, open Heat Control"
Then, I speak to set the temperature: "Set bedroom temperature to 25"

But, I want to discover and add my thermostat in Devices section of alexa.
So that I don't have to speak Invocation command everytime.

How can I use Alexa.Discovery with my Custom Skill?

Comment: Have you tried one-shot intent? `Alexa, ask Heat Control to set the bedroom temperature to 25`